# How to type a function to dynamically access an object’s property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to make this JavaScript function type safe. It takes a property name `prop` and returns an accessor function. The accessor function takes an object and returns the value of the property given by `prop`:

```js
function propertyAccessor(prop) {
    return obj => obj[prop]
}
```

Both `obj` and `prop` are known at compile-time. Here’s an example of how I intend to use this:

```js
// Good usage
const accessedObj = { date: new Date() }
const accessor = propertyAccessor('date')
const goodAccess = accessor(accessedObj)
```

I would like to type `propertyAccessor` in such a way that TypeScript can detect if I use it with a combination of `obj` and `prop`, where the object does not contain a property with that name. For instance, the following snippet should not compile:

```js
// Bad usage
const accessedObj = { date: new Date() }
const accessor = propertyAccessor('Helsinki')
const badAccess = accessor(accessedObj) // Should not compile
```

The following is my attempt ([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QU1VAngQQgkwGcS5UAeAFUUwA8pMwATExOAIwCtNoA+ABRoMALkQkoqGGADmASnGCu3cdXmIAvP0TUA2gGtMuOMF0BdRAG8AUInuJUmKCFRJlPNRu0ceekciIAIbsRiZm1OY2AL42NjJMqMBBxIgAIkFMLNZ2DiyZmOIZTDE2EAiSiPlZRQXZmtZVBeJgmADu6QWCGrE2APR9iADKABZwIAA22W0UBgA0EjKpAAbVmCzLiCMhwSjoWDi4iKsFyzYTzoiycHAshMRkWnsY2Hj3pOSoggDka9-ygjWLHkcQGwzGk2yYDgUEQ5QAtsgYBcFiQlphjkDNtt2NDngc8McABKYCZosAGGBnC6wzhBO5ED5PAKvAiMsgUH4kskySn-QF1eRAA)). The return type of `goodAccess` is `never`, while it should be `Date` or at least `Dated[keyof Dated]`. It also does not catch the bad access.

```ts
function propertyAccessor<T extends object>(prop: string): (obj: T) => T[keyof T] {
    return (obj: T) => obj[prop as keyof T]
}

interface Dated {
    date: Date
}
const dated: Dated = { date: new Date() }

// Should work, since `dated` has a property `date`
let goodAccess = propertyAccessor('date')(dated)

// Should not compile, since `dated` has no property `Helsinki`
let badAccess = propertyAccessor('Helsinki')(dated)
```

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/NV3xZm) is how I'd do it; you need to be generic in both the object and the key type, and you can only do so when you have values of those types (so `T` should be scoped to the returned function, not the outer function).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I was able to apply your approach to my situation, and I’d accept your answer.  While I didn’t ask for it in my question, you might add a note on specifying a default parameter to `propertyAccessor`, e.g. `prop = 'date' as K`, since default arguments are not possible without the assertion `as K` – as far as I could tell.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, but talking about default arguments seems like a digression and I'm not sure why I would mention it (as opposed to any other possible followup topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to make things [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both the type `T` of `obj` *and* the type `K` of `prop`, so that the type of the final result will be the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`.

Now if you were not writing a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, you could make `propertyAccessor` take two arguments, `prop` and `obj`, and you could [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be `keyof T`.  But that's not going to work.  When you call `propertyAccessor`, you call it with only the `prop` argument of type `K`.  And the compiler needs to infer `K` from that call, without knowing what you will do with the result.  That is, it needs to know `K` before it can possibly know about `T`.  So instead of constraining `K` to `keyof T`, you can only constrain it to some keylike type (in your case you already had `string` so we can use that).

So then `K` is essentially unconstrained except for being a `string`, and it returns a function which needs to be generic in `T`.  We need to express that `T[K]` is a valid operation, but it's too late to say `K extends keyof T`.  Instead we need to *reverse the constraint*: `T extends Record<K, any>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to say that `T` has some property with key `K`.

That gives us this:

```
function propertyAccessor<K extends string>(prop: K):
    <T extends Record<K, any>>(obj: T) => T[K] {
    return (obj) => obj[prop]
}
```

Let's try it:

```
interface Dated {
    date: Date
}
const dated: Dated = { date: new Date() }

let goodAccess = propertyAccessor('date')(dated); // okay
// let goodAccess: Date

let badAccess = propertyAccessor('Helsinki')(dated) // error!
// ----------------------------------------> ~~~~~
// Property 'Helsinki' is missing in type 'Dated' but required in 
// type 'Record<"Helsinki", any>'.(2345)
```

Looks good. The correct call is accepted and the incorrect one is rejected.

Note where the error appears for `badAccess`.  The call `propertyAccessor('Helsinki')` is fine by itself, as it has to be.  The compiler doesn't try to anticipate that you are going to do something wrong with that function, or that you should have called it with a different argument to fix the mistake you'll make later.  As far as the compiler is concerned, you are going to use that returned function to access the `Helsinki` property of some object.  And since `Dated` does not have such a property, the error is reported on `dated`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QU1VAngQQgkwGcS5UAeAaUUwA8pMwATExEqVGMAcwD4AFGgwAuRNQCUogFCJ5iSgBU6jZm0QAlTBAosaAGkQBDMLn5C4AIwBW4pZMQBefoiUBtagF1EAbzkKqJhQIKhIgtY2ji6Ike4iyF4yAL4yMjxMqMDGxIgAIsZMLH4B8iyFmOIFTCkyumCciOVFVRXFTn5NFeJgmADu+RWCjqkyADbBiLxwcCyExGTOKOhYOAREpOSoggDkzZg7koL7LJIA3IgA9JexANbGuDLXiBNQUzNzG2StNeOTVsZPgt2B0Etg8PNNhRdgAJTBjEg8W4wQ7HNqOZ7YdCoACETxuAFoicSSaSyeSKSTXAA-Wm0-GIAAKK3BuEQOzhCKRKMQMHYAFs+Yi+LykHgsOzqpgWDtEFYQG8ggBHEAwILFHiIBnizDs7S6VD6ABEnOFyKNRlM5h2ADpBAAmADMABYAKySIA)