# How to declare a generic function in TypeScript to have only one property of an object T to be of a specific type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a generic function declaration in TypeScript where I want to ensure that one specific property of the generic parameter type is always a string. Other properties do not matter.

Especially, I want to:

- only have this constraint for *that one* property, not for all properties - [I know there are numerous questions on StackOverflow that tackle this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659630/typescript-allow-a-generic-type-to-only-be-an-object-with-string-properties)
- do not hardcode the property this is about, but pass the property as `keyof T` into the function. - I could otherwise just use an interface or similar, that is easy.

### The problem

Here's a simplified version (MVE) of my function:

```
function exampleFunction<ObjectType>(
  items: ObjectType[],
  labelProperty: keyof ObjectType, // this one should refer to string
  uniqueIdentifierProperty: keyof ObjectType // this one can be anything
): ObjectType[] {
  // we somehow use and deal/assume `labelProperty` is a string.
  const stringValue: string = items[0][labelProperty];

  // other implementation does not matter
  return items;
}
```

Now this shows the error:

> TS2322: Type `ObjectType[keyof ObjectType]` is not assignable to type `string`.
>
> Type
>
> ```
>  ObjectType[string] | ObjectType[number] | ObjectType[symbol]
> ```
>
> is not assignable to type `string`
> Type `ObjectType[string]` is not assignable to type `string`

The function could be used like this:

```
type Dog = {
  idNumeric: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  breed: string;
};

type Car = {
  idString: string;
  manufacturer: string;
  year: number;
  model: string;
};

const dogs: Dog[] = [
  { idNumeric: 1, name: 'Fido', age: 5, breed: 'Labrador' },
  { idNumeric: 2, name: 'Rex', age: 8, breed: 'Beagle' }
];

const cars: Car[] = [
  { idString: 'car1', manufacturer: 'Toyota', year: 2020, model: 'Camry' },
  { idString: 'car2', manufacturer: 'Hyundai', year: 2021, model: 'Elantra' }
];

// Here are calls to exampleFunction
exampleFunction(dogs, 'name', 'idNumeric');
exampleFunction(cars, 'manufacturer', 'idString');
```

### Tries

I had a lengthy AI chat and between getting into the two errors above and either making the error of having *all* properties as strings, generating invalid code/code that did not what I want (it even confused TypeScript with C# once and produced me a `where` clause inside TS code) or it just said that it was not possible:

> Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't have the ability to dynamically enforce that a particular key will point to a specific property type. TypeScript's generics are powerful and provide static type safety, but there are limitations.
> Currently the generics are evaluated in a way that they cannot infer types dynamically from provided arguments. While `uniqueIdentifierProperty` is allowed to access properties of any type in `T`, enforcing `labelProperty` to only access string properties of `T` is beyond TypeScript's current abilities.
> This is a kind of conditional or dependent typing which TypeScript does not fully support at this moment. TypeScript's type system allows us to place constraints on generics and express some complex relationships between them, but a key/value pair constraint with dynamic key lookup like you mentioned is unfortunately something TypeScript can't enforce.

E.g. it suggested this (wrong) declaration:

```
function exampleFunction<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  items: T[],
  labelProperty: K & {[P in K]: T[P] extends string ? P : never}[K],
  uniqueIdentifierProperty: keyof T
) {
```

Probably misunderstood me, because the error shows this is not what I want:

> Type `T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]` is not assignable to type `string`
> Type `T[string]` is not assignable to type `string`

IT also used `Extract`, which sounds good, but only extracts the *property names* that are string-like, not the type of the value that a property refers to (respectively the declared type of the property):

```
function exampleFunction<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  items: T[],
  labelProperty: Extract<keyof T, string>,
  uniqueIdentifierProperty: K
): ISelectItem<T>[] {
```

Error:

> Type `T[Extract<keyof T, string>]` is not assignable to type `string`
> Type `T[string]` is not assignable to type `string`

Finally, however, it ended up with a working example that actually did not

```
function exampleFunction<
  ObjectType extends { [StringProperty in StringPropertyKey]: string; },
  StringPropertyKey extends keyof ObjectType = keyof ObjectType,
  AnyPropertyKey extends keyof ObjectType = keyof ObjectType
>(
  items: ObjectType[],
  labelProperty: StringPropertyKey, // this one should refer to string
  uniqueIdentifierProperty: AnyPropertyKey // this one can be anything
): ObjectType[] {
  // we somehow use and deal/assume `labelProperty` is a string.
  const stringValue: string = items[0][labelProperty];
  
  // other implementation does not matter
  return items;
}
```

However, IMHO this is hard to read/understand and not really straightforward to understand, so I asked the AI to explain that code part and this is what it said:

> In the declaration of `ObjectType`, the type is defined as an object that includes a key from `StringPropertyKey` which links to a `string` value.
>
> `StringPropertyKey` is a generic representing any key of `ObjectType` (which defaults to any key of `ObjectType`) and is intended to guarantee that `labelProperty` will only refer to `string` properties.
>
> Then we define `AnyPropertyKey` as any key of the `ObjectType` representation.
>
> `labelProperty` and `uniqueIdentifierProperty` are function parameters intended to take keys of the incoming objects. `labelProperty` is thereby constrained to `StringPropertyKey` which refers to a `string` property in `ObjectType`.
>
> At last, we have the function body where you assume `labelProperty` is a string.
>
> Please note that unfortunately, TypeScript may not fully enforce the constraint in the function as one would expect, allowing `StringPropertyKey` to refer to any property within `ObjectType` regardless of its type.

(I don't get the last sentence, but welll...)

Is not there a simpler solution? I mean having one property referred by keyof to have a specific type is not *that* uncommon of a scenario, so I wonder why that would be that complex?

TypeScript v4.5.2

**[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weL2YW)**

Comment: AI (ChatGPT) never ceases to amaze me in how many ways it can fail: https://tsplay.dev/WGXZ9w

Comment: The one problem ***I*** have with this kind of solution is that the error emitted is on the `items` argument and not `labelProperty`, which is quite counterintuitive.

Comment: If however, you agree with me, and seek a solution where the error emitted is on `labelProperty`, you can try using this: https://tsplay.dev/wgKbMw I can expand these comments into an answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but also how would you make the string also as optional/nullable? `Label extends KeysOfType<O, string | undefined | null>` does not work. Like here: https://tsplay.dev/WklX9w

Comment: You'll have to patch everywhere else that uses `Label`: https://tsplay.dev/NnM1Vw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type a function to dynamically access an object’s property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689264/how-to-type-a-function-to-dynamically-access-an-object-s-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got the right idea. We just have to clean it up a little, making use of the built-in `Record` type as a substitute for the mapped type, and removing the unnecessary defaults for the type parameters.

```
function exampleFunction<
  O extends Record<Label, string>,
  Label extends keyof O,
>(items: O[], labelProperty: Label, uniqueIdentifierProperty: keyof O): O[] {
  const stringValue: string = items[0][labelProperty];

  return items;
}
```

And this *works*, but it just rubs me the wrong way since the error is on the `items` parameter...

[image]

It just produces a confusing error message if you aren't familiar with how `exampleFunction` is defined. Ideally, the error should be emitted on the `labelProperty` parameter; that'd be more intuitive and helpful.

We can do that by directly constraining `Label` to only keys that point to strings instead. First, a utility to get said keys:

```
// extract keys left after mapping the keys and seeing if they are the right type
type KeysOfType<O, T> = keyof { [K in keyof O as O[K] extends T ? K : never]: 0 };
```

And now instead of `keyof O`, we use `KeysOfType<O, string>`:

```
function exampleFunction<
  O extends Record<Label, string>,
  Label extends KeysOfType<O, string>,
>(items: O[], labelProperty: Label, uniqueIdentifierProperty: keyof O): O[] {
```

This produces a much better error as you can see below:

[image]

However, it is worth noting that using this kind of definition can cause unforeseeable problems in the future. I'm not really sure when and why it happens but it's just something I've noticed with this kind of thing. If it starts emitting errors when you try to use `labelProperty`, just revert the change and go back to `keyof O` as the constraint.

Also, if you want to allow `undefined` for whatever reason, you'll have to use a mapped type instead of a `Record` again to add in the optional (`?`) modifier and patch everything else:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = keyof { [K in keyof O as O[K] extends T ? K : never]: 0 };

function exampleFunction<
  O extends { [_ in Label]?: string },
  Label extends KeysOfType<O, string | undefined>,
>(items: O[], labelProperty: Label, uniqueIdentifierProperty: keyof O): O[] {
```

[Playground (keyof O)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/PTAENAjAnB7BrApgO1IgHgQwLYAcA2iAsAFAQBmArsgMYAuAlrKhjgYgGLX1PIA8AFQB8AClIRQoBnUTYAzgC5QAgNoBdADTiwk-JkiJ8ABTi5E0OgE8lSS7HLKtZHaGoMAjpUQBJACYpGcgZzE1gzC2tQW3tlbVAASiVVNVAAbzjJCAB3RFA5WGxEAAtYLNc5XMxkX1B-THxgTDlKOULQAAM9A2NTcyt2qTlQTDy6aAZkAHMAOgzQGmY5OlHxqYA1eq8lJdXJ0ABeKRl5FQAGNRUuw1DwqzUAblI5iAY8QkLkOkxGZlrYRCGyFgy2w3xk0Dm0EQdEo0FQ0lkckezlAAF8niQqLQfiwsG9ONwcXxSJIAPJodAyapDABKiAW0F8fAAMvpDBoVhNJkInJJWd0KVTfENog5SU5RAj5EpSeoOVcemE+pF+ezXMgPF4-AEGEEQr0IjZEHYxYlQLKUukSJkwDk8gViqVypVqrVEPVGs1WrlOmzFbdLAMGEMRjsubNrfNFssw+tNohtmMuQcjoizhcFTdlQ8MTapPiPl8cX8AaAgSCweYSaAoTC4an5Mj0SRSFYzKAACKwPaHK2SBi+ABylEK4xoSmQI4M0GRkmQOATnKms+Gk0Xk+w05XMEQiF8id2TeRrcs7YAwphoCm+1JfABlJNTA9clegyfkTD0WHmZ-L6uWd1oAnKdzFfWB-HwX9JiPDEFmQJY-kmRRO27dQUxUatUlvYdRwYcdQAARg5edCiUAAiDgB1gMiOUwNclAAVg5Hc93I-loEwXxYGgMi0V5NJsJHcw8KUAAmYiF3Iul0Bo1dFwADmYqFWNAMiACF3UmQheNRJwcxbEg4IQmhL2Qi9oDQw4MMjLCBwfXZyJM6ACNkt9KA-L8oSA1SBFgOwvlkgDLzE05RNODlsHAwxyIvbBoEsHT+Ns+9H0mRzL1E1yqncz86x-VSAAlLGoXxMAYQLAJC0SiNASKIPIgBRPRPg4xLSH0uICvMSooXmep8CGOhYApNhCC4bFeFIVh8XGnhmBELikI5MiSMQWSyIHHDhJoMj4mRab2FmnERCcuRlrcjy8p45a7NS3bkSAA)

[Playground (KeysOfType)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/PTAENAjAnB7BrApgO1IgHgQwLYAcA2iAsAFAQBmArsgMYAuAlrKhjgYgGLX1PIA8AFQB8AClIRQoBnUTYAzgC5QAgNoBdADTiwk-JkiJ8ABTi5E0OgE8lSS7HLKtZHaGoMAjpUQBJACYpGcgZzE1gzC2tQW3tlbVAASiVVNVAAbzjJCAB3RFA5WGxEAAtYLNc5XMxkX1B-THxgTDlKOULQAAM9A2NTcyt2qTlQTDy6aAZkAHMAOgzQGmY5OlHxqYA1eq8lJdXJ0ABeKRl5FQAGNRUuw1DwqzUAblI5iAY8QkLkOkxGZlrYRCGyFgy2w3xk0Dm0EQdEo0FQ0lkckezlAAF8niQrGZQABpRCWOQAeXIAksZj4hI0yiEByi+JiqVAKhxUlQ0QchOGQ0JzJSGBk1SGAlAAH5caAlMhEAA3cxqJSnNHI0hUWg-FhYN6cbjqvikSSc-koXxDABKiAW0F8fAAMvpDFSdhNJkInJI7d00OgBSbcfiiSSyYgKY6xs7XaRRAj5EoeZpQFcemE+pEPQ7XMgPF4-AEGEEQr0IjZ6RzEqA42l9eAwDk8gViqVypVqrVEPVGs1WrlOvak7dLAMGEMRk6prMSJIFsglitnRt8FtZ1NadG5GcLombimHhjMmBXuwPl91X8AaAgSCweYq1CYXCjojkeiSKQsbkACKwPaHdITqS+AA5ShCnGGhJWAgxoGRSRkBwRBtjDKZoOGSZ4PPCDzGQmBEEQXwEN2J9lUxINQAAYUwaBaV-SQGF8ABlRDJnw51kNBZBKHITB6FhcxmKQqtLDbaBwOwSDWNgfx8D4yZCIxKcZ18L9FFAT9JnUWkVCrRlaKAkCGDA0AAEYqVgwolAAIg4WjYHMqlMFQpQAFYqWw3CLI9aBMEU6BzLRN00n-XTzH0pQACYTLgizzXQWyULQgAOFyoTc0BzIAITbSZCF81EnB3F8SHk5YaAo5TyOgdTDk0v9tPoxiLJK6BDNitiOK4u9eNSgRYDsL5YsEiiwtOULTipbAJMMCzyOwaBLBy-zaoY3YGoo0KWqqNruKhYTUoACUsahfEwBh+qEobQuM0BxskiyAFE9E+Tz5tIfK4l28xKiheZ6nwIY6FgL02EILg1V4UhWC1EGeGYERFMmOQqXM+zEFi8ydOA4KaHM+JkQh9gofVERGoR1LWs4rbzFR2iludbHkSAA)

---

If you really want to use `KeysOfType` and it keeps emitting errors, you should consider moving it to an external signature with an overload. Note that inside the body of the function you don't get the types anymore but to the caller it will appear as usual.

```
function exampleFunction<...>(...): ...;
function exampleFunction(...) {
    // magic
}
```